# Was Tevi a slave at death or not?

Tags: death, tractate-brachot, slave-serve-eved-avadim, bava-kamma

The gemarah (bava kama 74b) indicates that Rebbi Gamliel's slave, Tevi was given his freedom after his master blinded him in one eye. However, the gemarah elsewhere (Brachos 16b) indicates that Rebbi Gamliel accepted condolences on his slave Tevi's death. How do we resolve this?

Comment: Maybe he took condolences because they were good friends. I mean, they lived with each other for many years and it seems they talked about Torah too. Plus, it's not like an owner of a slave sits shiva when a slave dies, so why would you assume that gemara means Tavi was still owned?

Answer (score 8):

If you read further in the [Gemara Bava Kama 74b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9586&st=&pgnum=154) you see that although he blinded him he did not go free as there were no witnesses.

Comment: What a tzaddik!